# File `sdaps.cls' not found error

Tags: document-classes

I'm new to [SDAPS](http://sdaps.org/SDAPS). So after I followed [the tutorial](http://sdaps.org/Documentation/Tutorial) I tried with my own simple `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\title{Operating System MCQ Paper}
\date{\today}
\author{Menuka Ishan}

\begin{enumerate}

    \item \textbf{What is the reusable resource?}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item that can be used by one process at a time and is not depleted by that use
            \item that can be used by more than one process at a time
            \item that can be shared between various threads
            \item none of the mentioned

        \end{enumerate}
    \item \textbf{Which of the following condition is required for deadlock to be possible?}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item mutual exclusion
            \item a  process  may  hold  allocated  resources  while  awaiting  assignment  of  other
    resources
            \item no resource can be forcibly removed from a process holding it
            \item all of the mentioned
        \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This compiles without problem, but SDAPS can't build a project with this code. I don't know why?
After I analysed the `example.tex` in SDAPS I saw that there is `sdaps` instead of `article`, but when I compile using

```
\documentclass{sdaps}
```

it shows the error "`sdaps.cls` not found." Can anyone tell me correct way to create a LaTeX file for SDAPS?

Comment: Did you read here: http://sdaps.org/LaTeX ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download the latest release of the [`sdaps` bundle](http://sdaps.org/releases/); This tar ball should include a `tex` folder that hosts the TeX-related content (class file):

   [image]

   There is also a [Git repository](https://github.com/sdaps/sdaps).
2. Place `sdaps.cls` where TeX can see it. See [Where do I place my own `.sty` or `.cls` files, to make them available to all my `.tex` files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/5764)
3. Compile with

   ```
   \documentclass{sdaps}
   ```

For more information, read up on [SDAPS LaTeX support](http://sdaps.org/LaTeX).